# StackOverflowError: When Using julia Matrix Divide A/B [ partially solved !]

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, stack-overflow

Simply Get This Error by

```
rand(2,720)/rand(720,720)
```

ERROR: StackOverflowError:

When change it to

```
rand(2,120)/rand(120,120)
```

Get result:

```
2×120 Matrix{Float64}:
 -3.98568  4.0549   4.30112  0.767333  5.25419  1.03845   5.14592  0.236119  -1.46789  -1.83912   3.9814   1.09028   3.04451  0.618902  -4.33044  …  -5.36532  0.0215027  -9.72819  1.14866   -4.12121  2.24605  4.32528  -4.59007  -2.28853  -3.28813   1.13299   -1.2411    0.378753     
 -2.89095  2.27448  2.22753  1.13359   3.01714  0.929562  2.67707  1.18504   -1.02976  -0.569199  2.62177  0.517625  1.10433  0.294882  -2.43448     -2.79622  0.483641   -5.94725  0.903424  -1.92138  1.80968  3.08397  -1.97155  -1.31307  -0.971027  0.624244  -0.159086  0.249652
```

Changing 120 to 130:

```
rand(2,130)/rand(130,130)
```

ERROR: StackOverflowError:

Error Again !!!

Any function or package could solve this problem ? Thanks a lot !

[image: screenshot]

**Solution:**
just run

```
BLAS.set_num_threads(1)
```

in vscode terminal.

Maybe some loss of  performance (not tested) !

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Can you try it again from a fresh REPL session, and also add the output of `versioninfo()`?

Comment: versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.7.0-rc2
Commit f23fc0d27a (2021-10-20 12:45 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100F CPU @ 3.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-12.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
Environment:
  JULIA_EDITOR = code
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS =

Comment: This erro occurs when using Vscode . codes works fine when using Julia REPL

Comment: Ah, then it's a display problem. Can you edit it the complete stacktrace, please?

Comment: No more stacktrace, julia> rand(2,720)/rand(720,720)
ERROR: StackOverflowError:

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Unfortunately, I don't use VScode, but I'm quite sure it has to do with vscode-julia. You should find out the version of the julia extension/plugins and add them, too. Or maybe browse the issues on Github.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I'll change my IDE , as I'm not an expert . Aha ! Any advice on IDEs ?

Comment: I wonder if `b'\a'`, getting the result as 720x2 instead of 2x720, will at least work around the bug.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug, see:

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/vs-code-stackoverflowerror/72704

and the linked issue:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/43008

You could try with the latest master to see if it sorts it. If it does, the fix will be in Julia 1.6.5 and 1.7.1, to be released soon.